# How to get input value and insert it into database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have inserted manually some values of stars into database which i fetch and display against related products through this code which is successfully done now i want to insert the new value of stars into database when user click on stars against related product

> i use php as server side language and mysql database

```
 <?php
    include("sessiondestroy.php");
    include("functions.php");
    $ip = getRealIPAddr();
    include("header.php");
    include("leftside.php"); 
    ?>

                <td width="53%" style="align-left:15px;" valign="top" >
                <div class="row" align="center" >

                <?php 
                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"",'furniture_store');
                mysqli_select_db($con,'furniture_store');
                $query="select product_id, product_name, s_price, product_pick, rating from product";
                $run=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                    $id=$row['product_id'];
                    $name=$row['product_name'];
                    $image=$row['product_pick'];
                    $rating=$row['rating'];
                ?>

                <div class="col-md-3" align="center" style="border:#CCCCCC solid 1px; margin:15px; padding:8; ">
                <div class="container fill">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="index.php" method = "post">
                <table>
                <tr align="centr">
                <td align="center"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> &nbsp </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td ><img width="100px" height="140px"  src="admin/AdminLTE/<?php echo $image; ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> &nbsp </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left">
                <td style="padding-right:15px;"><input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.1" data-size="" data-show-clear="false" data-show-caption="false"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> &nbsp </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="userside_productdetail.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><input type="submit" name="detail" class="btn btn-success" value="Details"></a></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                </td>

    <?php include("rightside.php"); ?>
    <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    <script>
    $("#input-id").rating();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: By using the ajax

Comment: Use Javascript to dynamically update the value something like this  =>                                                  
 document.getElementById('input-id').value

Comment: It's a repeated question asked. There's so many questions asked on same topic. Get data from UI and save in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yawar you can use jquery $.post method to save your rating value to database and it is simple. But the thing is you have not mention which database you are using, what server side language you are using and even not mention rating reference. Is this rating is for user, product or comment or what so ever..

***Here we go:***
Although it is very basic example to get the result, but you need to work out more. The given example code is welcoming XSS and SQL injection attack. That part I can not cover here as it requires well understanding of all your code and apply it where it requires, that may need a lot of changes in your entire code. I hope you consider this sample code as an example only, not as a solution.

**Step 1:**
Change your

```
<td style="padding-right:15px;"><input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.1" data-size="" data-show-clear="false" data-show-caption="false"></td>
```

with

```
<td style="padding-right:15px;"><input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.1" data-size="" data-show-clear="false" data-show-caption="false" data-product-id="<?php echo $id;?>"></td>
```

**Step 2:**
Change

```
<script>
    $("#input-id").rating();
</script>
```

with

```
<script>
    $("#input-id").rating();

    $(document).on('change','.rating',function(){
        var prating = $(this).val();
        var product_id = $(this).data('product-id');
        $.post("updRating.php",{prating: prating, product_id: product_id})
        .done(function( data ) {
            if(data == 'Success'){
                alert( "Thank you for give your rating..." );
            }else{
                alert( "Opps!!! something went wrong, please try again" );
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

**Step 3:**
Create One PHP file for update rating for the product. eg. updRating.php as

```
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root',"",'furniture_store');
    mysqli_select_db($con,'furniture_store');
    $rating = $_POST['prating'];
    $product_id = (int)$_POST['product_id'];
    $query = "update product set rating = '".$rating."' where product_id = ".$product_id;
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
        echo 'Success';
    }else{
        echo 'Error';
    }

?>
```

Comment: sir thanks for your interest in my question, actually i am a new developer and i don`t know much about ajax and larval, i use php as server side language and use mysql as database. this ratting is for product sir not user and comments

Comment: @yawar I'll give you some sort of example code tomorrow, sorry bu today I'm in holiday mood :) . I'll definitely give you some good example code which will helps you to move forward.

Comment: @yawar I'd updated my answer with sample code, hope this sample will give you a hint to go into right direction.